# Replace Square Brackets with parentheses in Ruby

Tags: mysql, arrays, ruby, format

Using Ruby 1.9.

I have a array `[1,2,3]`

I need to convert it to a format `('1', '2', '3')` in order to apply it inside SQL queries (IN Statements) and the database is MySQL. Please suggest some good solution.

Thanks :)

Comment: Any database layer like [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) will do this for you. Don't do it on your own. Also, do try and upgrade your Ruby. 1.9 is past end-of-life.

Comment: @tadman: MySQL is not doing it automatically. Will try to upgrade, thanks :)

Comment: How are you making a connection from your Ruby code to the database? Are you using an ORM like `ActiveRecord`, `Sequel`, etc?

Comment: MySQL doesn't do anything automatically. You *must* use a library to properly compose SQL statements or you'll have to painfully write them yourself. ActiveRecord. Sequel. There are others, and I *strongly* encourage you to use one of them.

Comment: If it is raw SQL I doubt AR handles coverting array brackets to paranthesis since raw SQL goes straight to DB layer where it gets executed. I am looking for elegant solution, did you find one or rather made use of solution listed below?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the comments above not sure you still want to do this, but just for fun:

```
"('#{ [1,2,3].map(&:to_s).join("\',\'") }')"
#=> "('1','2','3')"
```

UPDATE: Based on comments from @tadman

assuming a SQL implementation here is some pseudo code:

```
irb(main):003:0> array = [1,2,3,4]
  => [1, 2, 3, 4]
irb(main):004:0> array.map{|id| "$#{id}"}.join(",")
  => "$1,$2,$3,$4"
irb(main):011:0> ["SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (#{array.map{|id| "$#{id}" }.join(',')})", array]
  => ["SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($1,$2,$3,$4)", [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: It should be `('1','2','3')`

Comment: I can't really give you something in parenthesis because that is not a object type in ruby. I would need to better understand how you want to use this?

Comment: Wrong. Dangerously wrong. This is not how you compose SQL statements. You **must** properly escape things.

Comment: @tadman: valid point. However, I was not thinking of the SQL implementation at all. I simply wanted to illustrate how to do the transformation of an array of values in ruby to a formatted string

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but this half-assed way of escaping is what causes [disastrous consequences](http://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/). It's for SQL, so it *has* to be handled correctly.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the heads up I've update my answer. any feedback would be highly appreciated

Comment: That's the idea. Some use `?` as a placeholder, others are named. Depends on your SQL layer. You may need to do an `each_with_index.map` there to pull out index numbers.

Comment: Yes I agree it would be dependent on the ORM, thanks for the feedback